# I need to seperate objects from each other in threejs i found a tutorial but he uses meshX = -10 and it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, animation

I need meshX to seperate the boxes from each other. This is in Threejs.

This is the code

```
meshX = -10; //error in meshX.
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 10);
    mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 10);
    mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 10);
    scene.add(mesh);
    meshX += 1;
}
```

Comment: PEMDAS means that `0.5 * 10` will get grouped together before the subtraction. I think you mean `((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add meshX at the x mesh position computation.

```
let meshX = -10;
for(let i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * meshX;
    mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
    mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
    scene.add(mesh);
    meshX += 1;
}
```

Comment: i tried to add the keyword "let" and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried swapping "var" with "let" in 'var mesh = new THREE.Mesh (... " ?

Comment: in js, var is different from let.
var can pass through the function while let is a local variable. But, I multiplied meshX on the x position by the random position to keep them away.